# Allow some of sections scrollable on set body: overflow=hidden

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I have a website with structure like

```
<body>
<section></section>
<section></section>
...
</body>
```

I set body{overflow:hidden} to disable scroll bar and use nav button to switch each section.
each section's default height is 100vh, and also has a min-height.
My question is : how Can I set the section scrollable which viewport height is less than min-height?
Thanks!

Comment: Set `overflow` for the section

Comment: Thanks for your quickly reply. I set section overflow as auto and scroll, but it doesn't work.

Comment: the scroll on the section or the body?

Comment: @RamboLi You can add a div for the content inside section and set overflow to section with 100vh as height. Something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/e1s71ekx/1/)

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/dkbq1d06/

Comment: Thanks @Dniel's great help. My problem was fixed with using media.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add overflow-y: scroll for the section tag

```
section{
   overflow-y: scroll
}
```